# Using GPG with org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, gnupg

What I want is to be able to make a 'heading' under which I can have encrypted data. I should be able to have multiple headings within the same file in emacs.

I had this working, but unfortunately I don't remember what I needed to do in order to encrypt the data. For reference, this is what I had to add to my .emacs to get it working:

```
(require 'org-crypt)
(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)
(setq org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance (quote ("crypt")))
;; GPG key to use for encryption
;; Either the Key ID or set to nil to use symmetric encryption.
(setq org-crypt-key nil)
```

What I've tried so far: using `:crypt:` before my heading, running `M-x org-encrypt-entry` on the heading.

Comment: Your problem is with the way you add tags : they should be put *after* the heading (try `C-c C-c` on the heading line to insert them).

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was doing that wrong and changed it, but still nothing happens

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you add space between `*` and `Heading` in your wrong string `*Heading :crypt:`? Also it doesn't have any spaces between beginning of line and `*`. Correct string has blue highlight, but wrong string is white.

Comment: Yep, it had blue highlight. I don't remember if I put the  space. Unfortunately, my computer's gone for service, so I'll check it out once it comes back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your config of org-crypt is enough to get it working. I have the same one and all headings with tag `:crypt:` are encrypted before saving file (with different passfrases). Also, running `M-x org-encrypt-entry` manually encrypts current heading.
Answer to your question can't be found with this description, it needed more details. For example: what happens if you running `M-x org-encrypt-entry` on heading? Org-crypt should ask passfrase and then replace text within heading. Or headings with tag `:crypt:` should be encrypted automatically before saving file.

EDIT: If current heading is syntactically correct (has blue highlight) and command `M-x org-encrypt-entry` produces error "Before first headline at position ... in buffer ..." then you can check value of variable `outline-regexp` (command `C-h v outline-regexp`). It may have incorrect value.

For me it is `"\\*+ "` in org-mode buffers.

Comment: It doesn't ask for anything, just says `Before first headline at position 1 in buffer testgpg.org`

Comment: I get same message `Before first ...` if cursor is on first line in file. Put cursor to heading:

    |* heading

and run command again.

Comment: Nope, only the position number changes

Comment: You have wrong behaviour of `org-mode` or wrong `* heading`, not `org-crypt`. If cursor is on `* heading`, you run command `org-encrypt-entry` and get this message `Before first headline at position ...`(which is generated by function `(org-back-to-heading t)`), then many functions of org-mode shouldn't work on same `* heading` too. For example, `M-x org-backward-heading-same-level` or `M-x org-insert-heading-after-current` shouldn't work.

Comment: My heading is `:crypt: *Heading`

Comment: `org-mode`'s syntax for headings requires `* Heading  :crypt:`. star(s) in the beggining of line, then space(s), name of heading, space(s), name(s) of tag(s).

Comment: Sorry for responding late; my computer had gone for service. This worked! Thanks!